# How to validate data is the same between a psql and snowflake table using hash sum?

Tags: postgresql, hash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, md5, amazon-aurora

I have a Postgres table that I am syncing into Snowflake and want to validate that all of the data in the pg table is in the Snowflake one. My idea is to do a hash sum of each column and validate it is the same, but haven't figured it out.

First, I tried using the HASH function in Snowflake and SUM to get a super convenient value, but PSQL doesn't support the HASH function, so I can't properly compare.

Then I tried to convert the column to text, concatenate using string_agg in PSQL and listagg in Snowflake, and HASH with md5 and compare values. This also didn't work because Snowflake can't handle large values with listagg (my table has 5B rows).

What would be the best way to do this? I'm open to totally different ideas as well!

Comment: Why not just count the rows? What is your sync doing that might alter data - as opposed to just dropping rows?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the open source [data-diff](https://github.com/datafold/data-diff) tool from Datafold. It's designed exactly for this usecase.